# Building Cocoa Touch dynamic framework from static library produces no binary

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, cocoapods, static-libraries

I'm trying to build GoogleMobileAds as dynamic framework from headers and static library using method 2 described here: https://pewpewthespells.com/blog/convert_static_to_dynamic.html

I've set up a project, and it builds successfully, however the produced framework contains no binary, only headers. Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

Sample project: https://github.com/HiveHicks/GoogleMobileAds-Dynamic-Wrapper

P.S. Building with XCode 8.1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

XCode doesn't produce framework binary if there are no `.m` files in the project. I added a dummy `.m` file, and it does now.

Comment: Or a .swift file.

Answer (score 0):

The sample does not copy the binary to the Bundle resources:

[image]

Doing so fixes the issue:

[image]

Comment: I don't want to do that, because the purpose of creating dynamic framework is to be able to use it as a pod dependency without Cocoapods being mad about "transitive dependency that contains static binary". Seems like I found the answer. Will post it soon.